# How to identify AWS RDS Scaling conditions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, load-testing

I have an application that is hosted in AWS ECS and having the database in AWS RDS. I'm using a microservice-based container architecture for my application. The frontend of the application is in Angular and Backends are in Java and Python. Right now, the database size is ~1GB. The database size will increase day by day as the scraped data will be inserted daily.

Right now, some queries are taking 4-6 seconds to execute. We need to host this application to the public and there are a lot of users will be using the application. So when we load tested the application with 50 users, I found that the CPU of RDS reached 100% and some queries had taken more than 60 seconds to execute and then timed-out. Also, the CPU and memory of other microservices (frontend and backend) are normal. I have tried vertically scaling the application up to 64GB RAM and 4 vCPUs but still, this condition remains.

Is this an issue with the query or can I do anything with the database server configuration?

The RDS storage I'm using is 100GB with a general-purpose SSD. So, I guess there will be only 300 IOPS, right?  I'm planning to use RDS read replicas but before that, I need to know is there anything that I need to do for improving the performance? Any database configurations etc?

I also not have a good idea about the MySQL connection count. Right now, it is using a total of 24 connections. Do I need to change the connection count also?

Comment: The first thing to check is your database design, which might not be optimal.  Then, you should use `EXPLAIN` on the queries which are taking too long.  Do you have appropriate indices setup, or have you done any other sort of tuning on your queries.  The last step, after exhausting these options, would be to scale vertically, or maybe partition, but this should not be your first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Query Optimisation

As Tim pointed out, try and optimise the queries. Since you have more data getting inserted, consider indexing the table and make the queries to use indexed columns if possible. also consider archiving unused old data.

#### number of connections

If you have control over the code, you can make use of database pools to control the number of connections that your applications can use.

#### CPU usage

the CPU usage is highly related to the performance of the queries, once you optimise the queries, the CPU usage should come down.

#### disk usage

Use the cloudwatch metrics to monitor the disk usage, based on that, you can decide on a provisioned IOPS disk.

hope this helps.